# Best practices for Scala physical directory structure

Tags: scala

Majority of projects uses Java like packaging convention where `.scala` files reside in the physical directory structure that aligns with package declaration. This is not strictly requires for Scala however it is easier to navigate code around. What is the official recommendation for this convention? I could not find any recommendations on official scala documents.

```
package com.company.project
class SomeClass {}
```

Should reside in?

```
com/company/project/src/scala/com/company/project/SomeClass.scala
```

Comment: It does not answer my question, it shows how projects are generally laid out. I am aware of Maven/Java packaging conventions. I need to convince non-JVM developer that it is better to follow Java convention. Looking for a reference from Scala official sources.

Comment: You should put Scala classes under the same package in the same package folder. There is no restriction for individual scala file name.